# Java PKCS12 Keystore generated with openssl BadPaddingException

Tags: java, ssl, openssl

I'm trying to configure undertow to use a keystore other than cacerts, but im getting the following error:

```
javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.doFinal(CipherCore.java:966) ~[sunjce_provider.jar:1.8.0_60]
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.doFinal(CipherCore.java:824) ~[sunjce_provider.jar:1.8.0_60]
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.PKCS12PBECipherCore.implDoFinal(PKCS12PBECipherCore.java:399) ~[sunjce_provider.jar:1.8.0_60]
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.PKCS12PBECipherCore$PBEWithSHA1AndDESede.engineDoFinal(PKCS12PBECipherCore.java:431) ~[sunjce_provider.jar:1.8.0_60]
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2165) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at sun.security.pkcs12.PKCS12KeyStore.engineGetKey(PKCS12KeyStore.java:348) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    ... 18 common frames omitted
Wrapped by: java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException: Get Key failed: Given final block not properly padded
    at sun.security.pkcs12.PKCS12KeyStore.engineGetKey(PKCS12KeyStore.java:410) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at java.security.KeyStore.getKey(KeyStore.java:1023) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at sun.security.ssl.SunX509KeyManagerImpl.<init>(SunX509KeyManagerImpl.java:133) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at sun.security.ssl.KeyManagerFactoryImpl$SunX509.engineInit(KeyManagerFactoryImpl.java:70) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at javax.net.ssl.KeyManagerFactory.init(KeyManagerFactory.java:256) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.undertow.UndertowEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.getKeyManagers(UndertowEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:304) ~[spring-boot-1.3.0.M5.jar:1.3.0.M5]
    ... 13 common frames omitted
Wrapped by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException: Get Key failed: Given final block not properly padded
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.undertow.UndertowEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.getKeyManagers(UndertowEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:308) ~[spring-boot-1.3.0.M5.jar:1.3.0.M5]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.undertow.UndertowEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.configureSsl(UndertowEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:258) ~[spring-boot-1.3.0.M5.jar:1.3.0.M5]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.undertow.UndertowEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.createBuilder(UndertowEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:244) ~[spring-boot-1.3.0.M5.jar:1.3.0.M5]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.undertow.UndertowEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.getEmbeddedServletContainer(UndertowEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:221) ~[spring-boot-1.3.0.M5.jar:1.3.0.M5]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.createEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:158) ~[spring-boot-1.3.0.M5.jar:1.3.0.M5]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:130) ~[spring-boot-1.3.0.M5.jar:1.3.0.M5]
    ... 8 common frames omitted
Wrapped by: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException: Get Key failed: Given final block not properly padded
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:133) ~[spring-boot-1.3.0.M5.jar:1.3.0.M5]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:531) ~[spring-context-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118) ~[spring-boot-1.3.0.M5.jar:1.3.0.M5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:667) [spring-boot-1.3.0.M5.jar:1.3.0.M5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.doRun(SpringApplication.java:342) [spring-boot-1.3.0.M5.jar:1.3.0.M5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:273) [spring-boot-1.3.0.M5.jar:1.3.0.M5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:980) [spring-boot-1.3.0.M5.jar:1.3.0.M5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:969) [spring-boot-1.3.0.M5.jar:1.3.0.M5]
```

All the `javax.net.ssl.*` properties are properly set.

The steps i took to generate the keystore were:

Firstly generate the private key:

```
openssl genrsa -out KEY_FILE.key -aes128 -passout pass:KEY_PASS 2048
```

The CSR:

```
openssl req -new -sha256 -key KEY_FILE.key -out CSR_FILE.csr
```

after my internal CA signed it, i create the keystore with the resulting CERT_FILE.crt:

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -in CERT_FILE.crt -inkey KEY_FILE.key -name NAME -certfile ROOT_CERT.crt -caname ROOT_NAME -passin pass:KEY_PASS -passout pass:STORE_PASS -out keystore.pfx
```

From what i've read so far, that error is usually caused by a problem with passwords, but my code is using the correct passwords for the key and keystore. Also, with:

```
openssl pkcs12 -info -in keystore.pfx
```

with STORE_PASS and KEY_PASS i can correclty see all the content inside the keystore.

Any hints on where should i further investigate ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Use only STORE_PASS.**

Java doesn't really support separate storepass and keypass in PKCS#12 like it does in JKS. In fact `keytool` tries to prevent you specifying different passwords, although until recently it missed at least one case I know of. And here it wasn't even involved.

More importantly, `openssl pkcs12 -export` *creates* PKCS#12 using only one password. `-passin` is used only to decrypt the input key file; it is not used for the output PKCS#12 and only `-passout` is used for that. `pkcs12 -export -twopass` does use two passwords (which must be prompted), one for MAC and one for both blobs, but if you do that which you didn't Java can't read the result anyway.

Alternatively, if you really want different passwords, convert to JKS:

```
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore ks.p12 -srcstoretype PKCS12 \
  -srcstorepass STORE_PASS -destkeystore ks.jks -deststorepass STORE_PASS
keytool -keypasswd -alias 1 -keystore ks.jks -storepass STORE_PASS -new KEY_PASS
```

Comment: Java doesn't even handle key passwords well in JKS keystores. JSSE for example provides no way to convey it to the SSLContext short of writing your own X509KeyManager.